# Surface 2.0 ScatterViewItem.Center load item and check if items on same position

Tags: position, pixelsense, scatterview

I've got a problem:

I capture the position of `ScatterViewItems`: `Center.X`, `Center.Y` and `Orientation`.

For example:

- Item1: X: 595,037655575406 Y: 322,207060644012 Orientation: 0,660569393375486
- Item2: X: 606,055258773819 Y: 327,601041845081 Orientation: 180,591312945756

If I load the items via code the position is not the same (it seems to be moved a few pixels).

The next issue is: I want to check if two items are exactly on the same position.

If true raise an event and lock the items.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use ActualCenter property and ActualOrientation property when reading it back.

The Center is moved? Check the margin of the ScatterView
Same Position?

```
Vector v = item1.ActualCenter - item2.ActualCenter;
if (v.Length < 10) //within 10 pixel distance
{
      //Raise your event
      item1.CanMove = item2.CanMove = item2.CanRotate = item2.CanRotate = false;
}
```